# Why can't moderators lift automated bans?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, banning

I have seen from various comments and in the rules of Stack Overflow that moderators *cannot* remove question or answer bans, no matter what.

How does the deciding who/for how long to ban and unbanning work exactly, if it is not the human moderators that deal with it?

Comment: No one bans or unbans a user from their question/answer ban; the ban is implemented, and lifted, automatically based on specific logic that is not public knowledge. When you go below the threshold then you are question banned, and when you go above it, it's removed.

Comment: Or are you asking, who determined what the algorithm would be?

Comment: @ThomA I was more just asking what the process is, to which your first comment was insightful, thank you.

Comment: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for mods to remove that ban, because the same algo which banned you in the first place would ban you again, because you're still under a certain threshold.

Comment: It’s more of a rate limit than an outright ban given the fact you can ask a question after 6 months. An answer ban is an outright ban since the same isn’t true.

Comment: I suspect the answer is mostly practical. If the moderators don't have the ability to shorten your question block, then there's no reason for you to post a Meta question asking them to do so. Nor is there any impetus for you to contact them through any other means.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*A preface: this is answering **why** the system works the way that it does.  Whether it's **good** for it to work this way is another matter entirely (I have my disagreements with some of the details).*

The post ban is not exactly a suspension that gets applied for a period of time like a moderator-applied suspension is.  Instead, it is a formula that decides, based on previous contributions, "is this user allowed to post right now?"  The only way to change the formula's output is to change its inputs, such as by removing poorly received posts from consideration, which moderators do not have the technical ability to do.

Comment: I'd be curious if anyone knows how often the formula is reviewed and revised and by whom. The rules and culture of the site have evolved over time -- has the formula evolved with this? Should it? The site has been in existance for 15 years, and has this been taken into account? For instance, is their any reduction of effect from old posts over time? Does, for example, a post made over 10 years ago, have the same effect as one made yesterday? Should it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels based on my observations of a handful of post-banned people whose negative post history is mostly _really_ old, no, I don't believe it does reduce the effect of old posts.  I do believe it should.  *(also based the number of times I've mentioned this around CMs without ever being corrected, although that's admittedly circumstantial...)*

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think the Q-ban was created at a time when being 15 years old wasn't even a consideration, so the idea of weighting or aging out old posts from the equation may not have been considered. I know that we don't really currently feel like it's a good method and there has been some hope that something like Staging Ground would be an opportunity to give users a way to ask questions while blocked from asking so that they could actually regain the ability.

Answer (score 20):

It is not a ban, I really dislike that word because it is often used where it does not actually apply, like to hype up a mere suspension. It is also a way where people make it seem that what is caused by personal responsibility is actually caused by someone else, as if it is done *to* them.

In the context of Stack Overflow what has happened is a *loss of privilege*. Just like you gain privileges based on built-in criteria, often lazily based on reputation score, you also lose privileges based on built-in criteria. It is not a matter of lifting a ban... what needs to happen is that your account no longer applies to the criteria that trigger the loss of the privilege.

Since the criteria are kept a secret, you can't force it. The best you can do is be a good citizen. Suggest edits, improve your own content, answer questions, don't get into trouble. And make peace with the idea that you will probably not be regaining the privilege to ask questions on Stack Overflow for an undetermined time.

An additional tool that the site provides to you is that once every 6 months you are in fact allowed to post one new question. This should not be treated as regaining the privilege to ask questions, it is merely a helping hand. If you manage to post a question which is well-received, it should help to tip the balance in your account. There is no guarantee that one question will be enough though.

Comment: I don't *generally* disagree with this sentiment but I also feel like the likelihood of someone succeeding in getting out of a ban is very low based on how it's currently calculated and the way people vote on posts or, should I say, downvote on posts. It's also very difficult to get upvotes since many people may be quick to downvote bad content but only upvote very high-quality content. Most users I've seen (not based on data) likely just get a score of 0, which does nothing to help.

Comment: @Catija indeed, I am not at all in agreement with how harsh it is. The fact that questions you posted and deleted when you were a student count just as hard 10 years later is ridiculously strict.

Comment: Ja. Joe Noob could have been a right idiot who was deservedly banned at 15, but by 25 has their smurf together and could be making worthwhile contributions to the site.

Comment: Certainly possible, I was a complete tool at 16. Now I'm more like half a tool.

Answer (score 11):

The ability to lift question/answer bans would greatly increase the pressure and the workload on the moderators, and would reduce the weight of community voting as a means of moderation.

If moderators were able to simply lift an automated ban, that would mean that all banned users would immediately ask for their bans to be lifted. This would put the moderators in the position to have to answer to every banned user why they believe that the ban is justified. This is obviously not scalable. In addition, by doing this, the ban would effectively not be automated, and the criteria would be made effectively public, since anyone could see the meta posts of the complaining users, and tell when they get unbanned and when not.

Another aspect is that if the moderators could unban users, this would mean that all the votes by other users that caused the ban, would be effectively canceled. It puts the moderators in a much stronger position against the community than where they are now.

Finally, it should be noted that in special circumstances, <strike>moderators</strike> staff can *already* unban a user. In cases where the user profile is generally okay, but they have a couple of heavily downvoted posts, e.g. due to the meta effect or the hot network questions effect (on bad answers), <strike>moderators</strike> staff can *disassociate* the heavily downvoted posts from the user's profile, thus improving the average votes on the user's questions/answers, and lifting the ban.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of people already ask to be unbanned by moderators anyway today irrespective of whether that's actually possible.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: That may be true, but I would assume that the number of requests would increase greatly if success was in fact possible :)

Comment: Mods can't disassociate posts. Only staff can. While we will do this for the purpose of removing a ban, it's a one-time offer and there have been cases where the subsequent questions are as bad as the removed ones... because the reality is, we need to do a better job of actually helping people ask questions well.

Comment: Sadly asking good questions is hard work. Anyone willing to do that work has likely also read the existing documentation on and about Stack Overflow in order to increase their odds of using it correctly. And that leaves us with the folk who want an answer, want it now, and couldn't be bothered to do the work to get it still asking and getting banned over weak-to-bad questions.

Comment: @Catija and people need to do a better job at wanting to ask questions well. They can't be helped if they don't want to be helped.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree that it's hard. I've struggled with it myself here on SO and that experience has left me unlikely to ask again unless I really have no other options. I (ab)use my access to the chat rooms to get help finding the answer if at all possible - lots of people don't have that option. The assumption that SO is a place for *asking a question* **and** getting it *now* is... a thing we don't address in the system. We prioritized ease of asking so much that it takes less time to ask a (bad) question than to search and find the question that may exist already.

Comment: One of the reasons I'm so excited about improvements to search is because I'm really hoping it'll do a better job of preventing duplicates than anything we've created up until now. I also feel like a solution that uses some method (honeypot or education or something) to prevent questions that are out of scope (belong on another site, out of scope, etc) would do a lot. I'd caution putting users into too narrow categories. I don't think a lot of people don't "want to be helped", @Gimby - I think they honestly don't understand how hard asking well is.

Comment: It's really easy for me to ping someone in Slack and say "Hey, I'm getting a 500 error when I try to edit a post. HALP!" but that's just an opening salvo. Lots of existing platforms rely on getting attention to a person first followed by fleshing out the details. That's not how SO is designed to work but I can't really expect people to understand that from the start when we don't really do enough to explain it clearly or make those explanations findable. There's a lot we think is obvious that we forget really... isn't at all. And I've seen very prolific answerers post bad questions, too.

Comment: When in school there is nothing quite like teaming up on a problem. Since that's a skill that carries over to pretty much any job, I wish it got more emphasis in school. Five or six of us would get together in an empty classroom and put together pseudocode and flowcharts and troubleshoot them. Then we'd separate to write the code ourselves to reduce bleed-over and mitigate plagiarism risk. Then we'd get back together to help each other debug and bulletproof. Basically a design session and design review, implementation, and then hand-over to the testing department.

Comment: I disagree that the votes would be effectively canceled. Votes are supposed to be on content, and the content itself would still be downvoted.